# What is the technical standard name for the USB connector used for Samsung Behold phone

Tags: connector, terminology, standard

I am in search of the technical name for the connector used for charging and data transfer in samsung behold sgh t919. One end is USB standard, what is the other end named? Is it an International or proprietary standard?

For photograph, please see http://www.walmart.com/ip/Insten-INSTEN-USB-Data-Charging-Cable-For-Samsung-Behold-Eternity-Omnia-Impression-Instinct/28883424

or

http://www.cellphoneshop.net/usbdacaforsa59.html

Comment: It is probably non-standard proprietary connector.

Comment: Strange; neither of those links work for me...

Answer (score 2):

It's a proprietary Samsung connector. Referred to as the Samsung 20-Pin Connector, or S20-Pin connector. It is used for multiple connections, including Audio, Headsets, USB, Serial and Charging.

See http://pinoutsguide.com/CellularPhones-P-W/samsung_d800_pinout.shtml for pinout.